# What is the difference between "climb on" and "climb to"?

Tags: word-usage, differences, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between "***climb on***" and "***climb to***"? As a pilot, there may be such minor differences in our aviation charts. But I can't quite understand the difference.

I am sharing the original version of the sentences here for you to understand. The meaning of phrases R-044 and R-051 simply refers to a course or path. We can simply call it an airborne path or route. But my request from you is that you just tell the difference between the two without reading the sentences.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Preposition ***to*** in your first example sentence is nothing to do with ***climb** [on]*. It's just the "glue" word attached to route **R-044** - which is effectively optional anyway (or could be replaced by ***up*** in most contexts without affecting the meaning). Compare *Climb the ladder to get to the top* and *Climb **on** the ladder to get there*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither *climb on* nor *climb to* are used as idioms in your examples.

For an aircraft, *climb* means:

> to go up, or to go towards the top of something:
>
> - The plane ***climbed*** quickly ***to*** a height of 30,000 feet. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/climb))

In this example, ***to*** simply shows direction. Also, ***climb*** is often used transitively. We say ***climb a mountain***, not *climb on a mountain*. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climb%20on%20a%20mountain%2C%20climb%20a%20mountain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) finds hardly any instances of the latter.

When you say that a plane climbs on a certain course, you use the preposition ***on*** just as when you give directions and say,

> Continue ***on*** the path along the lakeside. ([ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/on+the+path))

When you say that a plane climbs in a certain direction (*straight ahead*) ***to** intercept* you use ***to*** as part of an ***infinitive of purpose***:

> A to-infinitive can be used to express purpose:
>
> - I'm calling ***to** place* an order for delivery. ([Grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose))

So you can understand your second example as saying

> Climb straight ahead ***[in order] to*** intercept a certain route.